# Почему нельзя инициализировать переменную не в строке объявления? Но до обращения к ней

Tags: java

```
//так выдает ошибку при инициализации
public class Hello_World {
    public int id;
    id =100;
}

//а вот так работает
public class Hello_World {
    public int id = 100;
}
```

Comment: это просто не валидный синтакис

Comment: А в чём глубинный смысл такого объявления?

Comment: Ее можно в конструкторе инициализировать. А код, в т.ч. присваивания, должен быть внутри методов.

Comment: Не понятен ваш посыл инициализации в две строки, если достаточно сделать в одну.

Answer (score 1):

Это объявление переменной

```
public int id;
```

Объявление может быть с инициализацией

```
public int id = 100;
```

А это операция присваивания

```
id = 100;
```

Инициализация и присваивание - это разные синтаксические конструкции, хоть и выглядят похоже.

На уровне объявления класса возможны только другие объявления - объявления полей, методов, конструкторов и блоков инициализации. Операции могут быть только внутри блоков инициализации, конструкторов и методов.

**P.S.** Во время компиляции все операции инициализации нестатических полей будут автоматически перенесены в конструктор по умолчанию. Так что на уровне байткода присваивания отделены от объявлений.

Answer (score 0):

По идеи, нужно всегда инициализировать переменную чтобы потом не вылетало исключение NullPointerException. В данном случае как написал коллега.

> это просто не валидный синтакис – @Stranger in the Q

Совет такой, что лучше всегда инициализировать переменную при её создание, пускай это будет 0, null или для строковых переменных "", лучше всегда инициализировать, а в дальнейшем коде, если она Вам будет нужна, то присвоите ей значение, которое Вам нужно.

Не призываю Вас так делать, потому что это сугубо моё мнение)

Comment: В примере автора вопроса тип поля примитивный, так что поле автоматически получит значение по умолчанию.